# passing an array of arrays into a recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this problem where you are given an array of arrays. You start at the first item and them move either 1 item to the right or 1 item down depending on which item is bigger. the goal is to make it to the bottom right corner with the highest sum possible. Maybe I'm missing the point, but I figured this was a recursive function.

```
let map = [
        [8,3,5],
        [4,3,4],
        [2,2,3]
    ]

const find = (y,x,map) => {

    if (y === map.length - 1 && x === map[map.length - 1].length - 1){
        return map[y][x]
    } else if(map[y + 1][x] > map[y][x + 1]){
        return map[y][x] + find(((y + 1), x,map))
    } else {
        return map[y][x] + find((y,(x + 1),map))
    }

}

 console.log(find(0,0,map))
```

In this case the goal is to get 22 via 8->4->3->4->3, but whenever I pass the map into the next level of recursion, the array on the next level reads as undefined. Is there any way to pass down the array of arrays so that it can be read by other levels of the recursive function?

Comment: 8+4+3+4+3 = 22, but if you go 8+3+5+4+3 you get 23. So your algorithm to find the path with highest total is flawed. You want an actual pathfinding algorithm.

Comment: This isn't a recursive problem, When the array is 2 dimensional you can solve it just by changing your x and y coordinates.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it's not flawed - it's *sinful*! ...because it's greedy :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to get the greatest sum by moving only right or down, you could take an recursive approach by creating an exit condition first, with the last possible value and then take another exit condition if indices are out of bound (meybe here is a value of `-Infinity` better to omit this value).

Then take the real possible value and decide which value you like to return for getting a maximum.

```js
const find = (map, i = 0, j = 0) => {
    if (i + 1 === map.length && j + 1 === map[map.length - 1].length) return map[i][j];
    if (i === map.length || j === map[map.length - 1].length) return 0;
    let a = find(map, i + 1, j),
        b = find(map, i, j + 1);

    return map[i][j] + (a > b ? a : b);
}

let map = [[8, 3, 5], [4, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3]];

console.log(find(map));
```